# Is an identity functor in Category of sets a function application?

Tags: functional-programming, functor, category-theory

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/identity+functor

> The identity functor on a category C is the functor idC:C→C that maps
> each object and morphism of C to itself. The identity functors are the
> identities for composition of functors in Cat.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+application

> A function f is defined by its association to each input value x
> (belonging to some allowable domain of values) of an output value,
> usually denoted f(x) or fx. The process of passing from f and x to
> f(x) is called function application, and one speaks of applying f to x
> to produce f(x).

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set

Is an identity functor in Category of sets a function application?

The reason I ask this is in proguramming such as F#, pipeline operator

https://riptutorial.com/fsharp/example/14158/pipe-forward-and-backward

```
 "Hello World" |> print

 value |> f
```

Now,

```
 value |> map(f)
```

is generally recognized as functor.

In this understanding, a simple function application

```
 value |> f
```

should be an identity functor, is this correct?

Thanks.

### EDIT

**(endo)Functor**

```
value |> map(f)
```

**identityFunctor** (special case: `map` == `identity`)

```
value |> identity(f)
```

Therefore, **identityFunctor** is equivalent to

**function application**

```
value |> f
```

in another notation,

```
f(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

When translating from category theory to a programming language, replace "object" with "type" and "morphism" with "function".

When you say that `value |> map(f)` is recognized as functor, the functor part is actually related to the type of the `value`. This type was created by applying a type constructor to some other type. For instance, `value` may be a list of integers: the functor "list" was applied to "integer". Function `f`, in this case, operates on integers, but `map(f`) operates on lists of integers. We say that `map` "lifts" `f` to operate on lists.

Identity functor maps every type to itself. So, for instance, it maps type int to type int. In this case `map(f)` is the same as `f`: lifted `f` is again `f`.

Function application is a morphism. It takes a pair (a product) of the function type and the argument type and maps it to the result type. Here, it takes the pair `(f, value)`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. (I've watched your blog posts and YouTube lecture, a lot!) "Identity functor maps every type to itself. So, for instance, it maps type int to type int. In this case `map(f)` is the same as `f`: lifted `f`is again `f`." Yes. This is exactly my question...

Comment: I clarified this in my EDIT of my question. Please give me your additional thought. Thank you very much again.

Comment: One more question on your comment, plaese, Mr.Milewski... Perhaps I should make new question page, but you kindly have mentioned here. "Function application is a morphism."  This is what I've been thinking and wanted to ask you for a long time.

Comment: A function application `value |> f` is a morphism, and  a functor `value |> map(f)` can be said a general case (`identity` is a special case of `map`) of morphism.

Comment: In fact, in terms of CategoryTheory->FP translation, "object" is "type", "morphism" in category of set" is "function",  "function" is  a morphism of object->object, type->type, category->category, that is a functor. So, what I think is a function is merely a special case of funcor(higher order function)

Comment: Actually, I've questioned this to math guys, but they always claimed the definitions of Morphism and Functor are quite different which is Functor is structure preserving(that I know you also teach on this) and Functor 'maps' both "objects" and "morphisms", however, the fact is they can be interpreted as a same instance: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category

Comment: When you say, something is a morphism, you have to specify in what category. A functor is indeed a morphism in the category of categories. 

You can also look at a function as a (trivial) functor, if you treat a set as a discrete category, that is, a category whose objects are the elements of the set, and there are no morphisms between them (except identity morphisms). 

Category theory lets you look at the same thing from many different perspectives.